# Xcode 15 crashes when editing info.plist or other project information

Tags: xcode

I have tried cleaning my project and restarting my app.

Unfortunately, the error message is not readable, so I can't make anything useful out of it.

[image: Crashing]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is a known and reported issue. It's a result of adding the NSLocationTemporaryUsageDictionary in the new Automatically Generated Infoplist file. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/691232

I solved this issue by moving the NSLocationTemporaryUsageDescriptionDictionary from the auto-generated Info.plist to the manual Info.plist.